# How to calculate two datetime's month difference?

Tags: python, datetime

How to calculate two datetime's month difference?

If I have two datetime, such as: `2017.01.01` and `2018.04.01`, the months difference is `15`. (`2017.01.01` ~ `2018.04.01`)

But how can I calculate it?

Comment: @RoadRunner this is clearly a duplicate. Thanks for the link, next time can you vote to close?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sure thing, I was about to. You closed it before I was about to cast my vote ;).

Comment: I closed it too late apparently :) see below...

Answer (score 0):

**code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta


date1 = datetime.strptime(str('2017.01.01'), '%Y.%m.%d')

date2 = datetime.strptime(str('2018.04.01'), '%Y.%m.%d')
r = relativedelta.relativedelta(date1, date2)
print(r.months)

r = - (r.months + r.years * 12)
print(r)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
-3
15
```